# how to write a function that return a type which is return type of its sub-functions

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that calls several sub functions and return the result of these sub functions.

```
sub functions:
template<class A> A sub1(A a)
template<class B> B sub2(B b, int i)
template<class C> C sub3(C c, string p)
```

THE function will call these accordingly in the switch statement.
Sorry I only have pseudo code since I am confused with the issue and not start to write the code.

```
mf(string s)
{
  int k;
  k = process(s)
  string
  switch (k){
  case 0:
    return sub1(k);
  case 1:
    return sub2(s, k);
  case 2:
    return sub3(k, s);
  default:
    break;
  }
}
```

How can I define mf above since there is no return type for it now? using template again?
By the way, my c++ compiler does support c++ 11 standard which I am not so familiar with.

Comment: If they are only simple functions, why do you need to use templates? Seems like overkill to me

Comment: You could return a [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html), which would allow you to return different types and even a null type for your break case (using `boost::empty` as one of the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is basically a static-typed language, which means all types of expressions are decided at compile time rather than at run time.

Using dynamic-typing in a static-typed language is possible, but not recommended for widely use. Because doing so you're giving up almost all the polymorphism features provided by the language. You'll have to check types manually, or implement your own dynamic-type-based polymorphism.

If the data returned is not too complex, tagged structure is usually a good idea:

```
struct Value
{
    enum {INT, FLOAT, PTR} type;
    union
    {
        int   int_data;
        float float_data;
        void *ptr_data;
    };
};
```

For more complex data types with a lot of operations needed to support, you should consider using abstract interfaces and inheritance.

If you considered the problem seriously and believe that none of those methods above applies to your problem, and that dynamic typing is the best way, here are some options:

- `boost::any` -- A unique container for all types. Need to test for types and convert them manually before use.
- `boost::variant` -- A union-like container which supports unary polymorphic operations via `boost::static_visitor`.
- Some programming frameworks have their own support for dynamic-typing. One example is `QVariant` in Qt. If you are in such a framework, it's usually recommended to use them instead of something else from another library.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Just as I wrote above,I want to write an interpreter for SCHEME in C++ in which expression will be evaluated to a value.The value may be a number,a string,a list etc. which can only be clear after the evaluation.

Comment: @user1461328: There're only a few basic types in scheme so I would prefer boost::any with a tag. :-)

Comment: @user1461328: boost::any does provide a type() function so the tag is not necessary. Sorry for my mistake. The answer has been corrected.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a function that returns the value of its sub function you need the same return type for all of them.

Here a small meaningless example:

```
double calculatedPositive(double value)
{
    // Do stuff
}

double calculatedNegative(double value)
{
    // Do stuff
}

double functionA(double value)
{
     if(value > 0)
         return calculatePositive(value);
     else
         return calculateNegative(value);
}
```

P.-S. We could provide you with a better answer if you'd say what you are trying to achieve ;)

Comment: Actually I want to write an interpreter for SCHEME in C++ in which expression will be evaluated to a value to be used by another expression.